# postgres sql GROUP BY DATE with LEFT JOIN does not list ALL records from the right table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, left-join

I am attempting the group by date of an attendance timestamp and at the same time list all employees of the grouped date. And regardless if there is entry in the attendance, I'd like to list all available employee.

Here is my attempt to produce the query, but it lacks listing all the employees for every generated date.

Please refer to my attempted sql code:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a971a7ac01fb2f4bc7458983c40a24bf

```
SELECT 
    a.created_at::date as created_date,
    a.employee_id,
    e.name,
    e.division_id,
    MIN(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1) as min_time_in,
    MAX(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
FROM
   attendance a
LEFT JOIN employee e on e.id = a.employee_id   
GROUP BY created_date, a.employee_id, e.name, e.division_id
ORDER BY created_date, a.employee_id
```

the result shows like this:

```
created_date    employee_id name    division_id min_time_in max_time_out
2020-11-18  1   John                    1       07:10:25    20:01:05
2020-11-18  2   Amber                   2       07:30:25    19:10:25
2020-11-18  3   Mike                    1       07:50:25    19:22:38
2020-11-19  1   John                    1       07:11:23    23:21:53
```

However, my goal is to list all employees and group the employee_id records by date. regardless if there is attendance by the employee, it should show a row of the date. How can I generate a query that produce like below:

```
created_date    employee_id name    division_id min_time_in max_time_out
2020-11-18  1   John                    1       07:10:25    20:01:05
2020-11-18  2   Amber                   2       07:30:25    19:10:25
2020-11-18  3   Mike                    1       07:50:25    19:22:38
2020-11-18  4   Jimmy                   1       null         null
2020-11-18  5   Kathy                   2       null         null
2020-11-19  1   John                    1       07:11:23    23:21:53
2020-11-19  2   Amber                   2       null         null
2020-11-19  3   Mike                    1       null         null
2020-11-19  4   Jimmy                   1       null         null
2020-11-19  5   Kathy                   2       null         null
```

Comment: You need `generate_series` on the left end of a left join.

Comment: Left to right in the `FROM` clause: `generate_series` of dates (or extract distinct dates from table `attendance` if you want to skip dates with no attendance at all), `cross join` it with table `employee` and then `left join` with table `attendance`.

Comment: generate_series for dates would be great. would be great if can provide some solution this. Im reading up generate_series anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
     d::date AS created_date
  ,  e.id
  ,  e.name
  ,  e.division_id
  ,  MIN(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1) as min_time_in
  ,  MAX(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
FROM    (SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM attendance) AS r(startdate,enddate)
  , generate_series(
        startdate::timestamp, 
        enddate::timestamp, 
        interval '1 day') g(d)
    CROSS JOIN  employee e
    LEFT JOIN   attendance a ON a.created_at::date = d::date AND e.id = a.employee_id
GROUP BY 
    created_date
  , e.id
  , e.name
  , e.division_id
ORDER BY 
    created_date
  , e.id;
```

edit: id from employee selected, instead of employee_id

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d27c681d14049126072aacd07e4aab6c <-- I think its not working properly. I removed records for 2020-11-19 also. employee_id is also null in some cases.

Comment: You changed the fiddle, there are no records on the 19th. I changed the end date to current_date, to make sure it selects everything between the 18th and today.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9281dd4cc486df4c7e09f064d03e400a <-- I modified slightly by putting 21th record and interval to 2. seems to be skipping 2 days. doesnt seem to go from 18th to current date all the dates or the dates within the table range.

Comment: Check the current query

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=abc6903804dbf0ebb4d3e23699a2880c <-- here is the current query in execution. something is odd on the result. not all dates are inside and min_time_in/out is not in the results

Comment: Check my current query, using (SELECT MIN(created_at), MAX(created_at) FROM attendance) AS r(startdate,enddate) to select the date range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225457/discussion-between-frank-heikens-and-axil).

Answer (score 1):

Just cross join the distinct dates from your attendance table with employee table.
You can try like below:

```
select
a1. date,
e.id,
e.name,
e.division_id,
MIN(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1  ) as min_time_in,
MAX(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
from 
employee e left join (select distinct date(created_at) "date" from attendance ) a1 on true
left JOIN attendance a on e.id=a.employee_id and date(a.created_at)=a1.date
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1,2
```

Note: `left join on true` is equivalent to `cross join`

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ea122617073b5954afd3172f88e2ce4)

UPDATE:

If you want the output for all dates between min date and max date.

```
with cte as (select min(created_at)::date "mindate", max(created_at)::date "maxdate" from attendance )

select
a1. date,
e.id,
e.name,
e.division_id,
MIN(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 1  ) as min_time_in,
MAX(a.created_at::time) FILTER (WHERE a.activity_type = 2) as max_time_out
from 
employee e 
left join (select g.date from cte, generate_series(cte.mindate,cte.maxdate,interval '1 day') g(date) ) a1 on true
left JOIN attendance a on e.id=a.employee_id and date(a.created_at)=a1.date
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1,2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=098c3abf44c4d8a9df841bf56aceb2de)